# How to add a path inside a data table entry

Tags: java, jquery, html, datatable, liferay

This is my current code snippet for the displaying of data in a data table on liferay 7

```
 <table id="gbdb" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

  <c:forEach items="${guestbookList}" var="guestbook">
       <tr>
       <td>${guestbook.name}</td>
       <td>${guestbook.status}</td>
       <td><a href=/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp></a></td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

It is currently able to display the name and status but i wish to reference the third column inside a jsp file where the button and its function will be located.
How do i get along doing this??

Comment: Do you want to link to that other JSP (as you do with `<a href=...>`) or do you intend to include that other JSP's output into your own page? What do you mean with "I wish to reference..."? Reference from where - from Javascript?

Comment: yes i wish to set the path to "/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp"

Comment: "set the path" for what? I don't understand: Do you want to post a clickable link to that page? Do you want to include the HTML generated by that page in the JSP that you posted above? What's the underlying problem?

Comment: guestbook_actions.jsp contains an action button for add/delete...i just wish to set the path in my table column so that column will display an action button

Comment: @Liferayer : do you want to add code form "guestbook_actions.jsp" in your <td> tag or do you need button in <td>tag on click of which you need to redirect on "guestbook_actions.jsp"

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to display code from 'guestbook_actions.jsp' file in your last column in your  tag.

you can try **<%@ include file="file" %> directly in your td tag**

```
 <td><%@include file="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your previous questions suggested that you're working on Liferay's [guestbook tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-a-user-interface). In there you find

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
    align="right" 
    path="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" />
```

which will embed the output of that JSP into the current JSP, but it might require the use of the Liferay search-container tags (it might as well work without - try it)

Alternatively, there are two options in raw JSP,

```
<jsp:include page="..." />
<%@ include file="filename" %>
```

You probably want the first one.

Comment: you probably might not notice but i am currently using the <c: method to populate data inside a html opening and closing {} even though its on a jsp file..